# Transitioning to a new child with a custom transition in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

[**AnimatedSwitcher**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) is the basic version of what I want to achieve. When the child changes to a new child, the old one transitions out and the new one transitions in using the specified transition.

However, I want the old child fade out and new child fade in to have different animations. Just as an example, I'd want to fade the old child to white (opacity 1 -> 0) in 1s and 0.5s in I want to start to fade in the new child (scale 0 -> 1).

*It doesn't really matter what the different transitions are, the goal is to switch to a new child (the old one is unloaded afterwards) and during the switch to animate both children in different ways.*

I'm wondering how to properly achieve this and I'm stuck because I'm very new to Flutter and its Transitions.

Comment: `AnimatedSwitcher` has [transitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher/transitionBuilder.html) property - pass it to `AnimatedSwitcher` constructor

Comment: That only allows me to define a single transition which will be used for both children

Comment: yes, and you want to use completely different transitions? how would it play? if you you want what you described use different curves

Comment: as I described in OP - the child being faded out should fade out using 1 animation and the other one being faded in should fade in using another animation. how do I achieve this?

Comment: if you you want what you described use different curves when creating `AnimatedSwitcher`

Comment: Can you provide an example? Or a link to a resource that describes how to do this?

Comment: use `Interval` for example and/or `Curves` class that contains alot of predefined curves - also you can create a class that extends `Curve` class too